# Getting the first word of string from an argument

Tags: bash, shell

Basically what I'm trying to do is to create an if condition to evaluate whether the program has been launched with a specific argument.

Basically you have three launch options for the program

```
./testprogram
```

or

```
./testprogram [-i EXCEPTION] DIR
```

What I'm trying to do is, determine whether the program has been launched with one of the arguments. Here are the launch options :

- if launched with no arguments, it will set to current working directory
- if launched with exception it will perform a specific task
- if launched with DIR, it will set DIR as the set argument

So I created the following function

```
parse_arg(){
  # when launched with no argument, fairly self explanatory
  if [[ $# == '0' ]]; then
     DIR="$PWD"
     DIR=$DIR
  fi
```

Now here's the tricky part, i need to figure out a way, to check whether the second argment is -i exception or simply dir, in other words, i just cant hardcore it to amount of arguments we've launched it with. What I tried to do is create a parameter to help me with establishing the if condition

`I_DETECT="$1"`
Now what I'm not sure if, how to basically cut the words inside the string while also maintaining whitespace control.

Only way I can think of to do that is to basically echo it out and then using the cut function. Issue is, i need to echo it out

I tried this

```
I_DETECT=$(echo I_DETECT | awk '{print $1;})' 

  elif [[ $# == '1' && $I_DETECT != "-i" ]] then;
  ... #you get the point
```

Issue is with nature of awk tool it still ends up printing it out to STDOUT, when all i want is to evaluate the expression for the if condition.

So any ideas for more elegant solution?

Comment: I have multiple questions: (1) What's the pupose of `DIR=$DIR`? (2) Why do you want to cut the words inside `$1`? A correct call of `testprogram` has either `$1 = -i` or `$1 = someDir`. The `"-i"` is only one word and `someDir` probably shouldn't be splitted. (3) What do you want to to with the splitted words: Put all words into an array, just extract the *n*th word, ...?

Comment: Are you looking for `shift`? Also, read up on [Bash FAQ/035](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) and [ComplexOptionParsing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ComplexOptionParsing).

Answer (score 0):

`getopt` is a good way to parse arguments, including `--long-options`. It will avoid the most tedious parts of this job.

Comment: Also, for simpler requirements (like no long options), the builtin `getopts` is available.